# scrolling to bottom of fixed positioned div

Tags: css, html, scroll, css-position

I have a fixed position side tab on my page that contains filtering options for the user. When there are a lot of options, the side tab gets too long and the bottom goes beyond the bottom of the page, where it is impossible to view.

Is there a way to have the whole page continue scrolling to the bottom of the side tab div? I don't want to put scroll bars inside my side tab div, even though that would be an easy fix.  I just want, when the bottom of my div butts against the bottom of the page, to bring the whole div up with it so that the bottom content is visible.

I am limited in that I can't use jQuery in this particular application. I can, however, use Dojo.

Comment: You count the number of options shown in the div. If it crosses the value after which it touches the bottom of page give some value to the tab div.
You have to do this either in javascript or in code behind by adding runat="server" to the div and the inner controls.

Comment: No, the problem is a purely CSS problem. I want that sidetab div to remain fixed in the middle left of the page, but if it gets to be say, 800px tall, I can no longer see what's at the bottom of the sidetab. I'm trying to figure out a way to do that without using scroll bars. Which may be impossible...

Comment: You want to show div which contains data of height 800px in 300px without using scrollbar....... then you have to control the font size and line height dynamically, so that the content will fit into div, otherwise i dont think there is any way.

Comment: I was afraid that was the case. Thanks :)